# '"erl.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix, elixir-iex

'"erl.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Elixir and Erlang were running fine until today when I did a version update.  I don't really have access to a good version manager for Elixir since I use a windows computer so I just ran the Elixir install wizard to uninstall and reinstall to update the version.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled a couple of times as well as checked the elixir forum for solutions (there was 1 solution, it didn't work) for solutions.  I need to get Elixir up and working pretty quickly as I am about to start on my first contract.

Comment: Does Elixir bin path exist in your PATH? 
https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#setting-path-environment-variable

Comment: Yes it is, now I am unsure if I need to add the Erlang bin as well but I have tried it and it hasn't done anything for me.

Comment: Someone on the elixir forum figured it out, I had the erlang bin and elixir bin on the path but the erts bin wasnt.  Erts is usually inside your erlang folder.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
erl <'command details'>
```

Try to run using "./" prefix so it become

```
./erl <'command details'>
```

in the cli.

Answer (score -1):

I am also using windows and have added elixir, erlang and erts paths in env. But still, it is giving me the same error. I am not getting the error. I did not update the version. My system was slow hence I deleted some files, but they were explicit. They didn't have anything to do with the elixir folder.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32391095)